# How to compare generic objects in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

consider the following simplified snippet:

```
class Foo<T: Equatable> {
    var x: T
    init(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
        self.x = x
        if (x == y) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this class to work for all kinds of `T`s that are somehow comparable. Ideally it would compare the identities if T is an object and directly compare everything else that conforms to `Equatable`.
The code above doesn't work for `Array` for example. If I change `Equatable` to `AnyObject` and `==` to `===` then it doesn't work for `Int`s. How do I solve this problem? I thought about creating my own protocol but then I couldn't figure out how to implement it for all types that conform to `Equatable`.

Edit:
I didn't know that it would work on the Mac because I am on Linux and when I try to compile

```
Foo<[Int]>([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

I get the following error:

```
error: type '[Int]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
Foo<[Int]>([1, 2], [1, 2])
^
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  It won't compile if you try initializing it with arrays?  What's the error message exactly?

Comment: @nhgrif A generic array cannot be equatable, in the direct sense, but rather contain elements which are equatable. But I agree reading the Q again that this is kind of unclear (that was, however, my interpretation of the Q).

Comment: Using the code in the question, I am able to call this code: `let f1 = Foo([1,2,3],[1,2,3])` which works perfectly fine (and says they're equal).  What makes this not work?  Moreover, even if the array has multiple types, such as: `let f1 = Foo(["string",2,3.14],["string",2,3.14])` it works just fine (and says they're equal).

Comment: @nhgrif Try using a Swift native array rather than `NSArray`: e.g. `let f1 = Foo<Int>([1,2,3],[1,2,3])`

Comment: Those are Swift native arrays.  They do appear to be toll-free bridged to Objective-C arrays... but who cases?  It's toll-free bridging.  I'm going to close this question as unclear until the ***actual problem*** can be clearly identified.

Comment: @nhgrif I agree that the question could indeed be more specific, but I also think it's quite clear the OP states that his/her generic does not work as intended for e.g. `Array` instances (which is not equal to `NSArray` instances).

Comment: Every question on Stack Overflow states that the given code doesn't work as intended.  What is lacking here is the actual error (arguably, how to reproduce it [by removing `import Foundation` is the only way]), and arguably *why* it's actually a problem.  As far as I'm concern, the solution appears to be to `import Foundation`... why doesn't this work?

Comment: I'm talking about native Arrays as I'm on Linux. I will add the exact error message as soon as I'm home again but it said that Array does not conform to Equatable

Comment: @nhgrif I edited the question with the specific error message

Comment: @nhgrif I cannot `import Foundation` because on Linux there is no Foundation

Comment: @eyelash Yes there is Foundation, it's just not finished yet, it's a work in progress: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md

Comment: @EricD. oh wow I must have missed that. However I still get the same error even with `import Foundation`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to simply add another initializer for arrays of `Equatable` elements.

```
class Foo<T: Equatable> {
    init(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
        if (x == y) {
            print("Initialization by equal equatable types.")
        }
    }

    init(_ x: [T], _ y: [T]) {
        if (x == y) {
            print("Initialization by equal arrays of equatable types.")
        }
    }
}

let a = Foo<Int>(1, 1)
    /* Initialization by equal equatable types. */
let b = Foo<Int>([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
    /* Initialization by equal arrays of equatable types. */
```

Comment: I probably simplified my code a bit too much. The variables I am comparing are actually stored properties so I cannot just overload the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you intend to do with Foo, it may not be necessary to make it a generic class but rather just have generic initializers:

```
class Foo 
{
    init<T:Equatable>(_ x: T, _ y: T) 
    {
        if (x == y) 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    init<T:AnyObject>(_ x: T, _ y: T) 
    {
        if (x === y) 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

// in Playground ...

class Bar { }

let C = Foo(3,4)  // no error

let O1 = Bar()
let O2 = Bar()

let D = Foo(O1,O2)  // no error
```

Comment: This will not work.  `AnyObject` itself conforms to `Equatable` and as such, any time you try to initialize `Foo` with anything inherited from `AnyObject`, you will get an error: `Ambiguous use of 'init'`.